# Using Net.exe, how do you add a user group with a 'Description' field as shown in Windows Computer Management?

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments

I knew how to add a user group using net.exe:

```
net localgroup/group madeupgroupname /add
```

This simple question was eluding me, perhaps because it is obvious: "How do you do this, and change the description that appears when you view the groups in computer management?"

I saw the code:

```
net localgroup/group madeupgroupname /comment:"This is a comment." /add
```

But a comment is not a description...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the comment is the description, so this is the answer:

```
net localgroup/group madeupgroupname /comment:"This is a comment." /add
```